# Where do I set the Xcode IDE property to read a data file to avoid No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, file, ide, location

This is not a code question but an Xcode IDE question.
For those who pride themselves in code analysis, that's good, but in this case, please try to focus on the question in the Title above not the code.

In the Xcode IDE I created a new project and selected a "Command Line Tool" creating ReadAFile.
I then entered some simple code into main.c to read and display the contents of "Data.txt".
I then selected File, New, File, and selected Empty (For an empty document) and named it Data.txt and then I typed out a sentence then saved the file.
In Xcode, when I choose Product, Run, I get the following error:

```
Error while opening the file.
: No such file or directory
Program ended with exit code: 1
```

Where do I set the Xcode IDE property so that it knows where my data file is to avoid getting the "No such file or directory" error?

When I enter the very same code into ReadAFile.c and I type out the very same file "Data.txt" at a terminal prompt using vim, save it, and run make ReadAFile, the code executes properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char ch, file_name[25];
    FILE *fp;
    strcpy(file_name,"Data.txt");
    fp = fopen(file_name,"r");
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);
    while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
        printf("%c",ch);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question... I have a temporary, work around, answer...
I do respect your request to focusing on the question rather than your code.
As a quick temporary answer, the only answer I have for you at this point is to modify your code, for now, if you are only debugging your code along with your data file. ***I know hard coding your file locations is a no-no*** but for debugging purposes ***the following will get you over this bump in your road***. You can try to hard code the directory location along with your data file so that your code can find it. For example, let's say that your Users directory on your Mac is jerryletter, you could copy your Data.txt file to your Users directory ~/jerryletter. Then  could modify just one line of your code like the following:

```
"strcpy(file_name,"/Users/jerryletter/Data.txt");"
```

DougPan.com

Comment: SOLUTION: In Xcode look down the left hand column for a folder icon called "Products". Under it you will find the name of your executable. Click once on it and then look over to the RIGHT hand column and click on the "File Inspector" icon. There you will find the directory where your file is being executed from. You can simply click on the arrow just after the directory and place your data file in there and it should find it. This allows you to place your file in a relative location as opposed to a fixed, hard coded method I mentioned earlier.